# Find number of commits difference between two Git hashes

Tags: git

Say I have these two commits from a Git repo

```
06c839536ba38c0cd78fb031af94cfa35e0fd0ba 
97f22113a5e681c30460f764b1ac35afc5163a1d
```

Given that info, how can I find the number of commits difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --oneline 06c839536ba38c0cd78fb031af94cfa35e0fd0ba..97f22113a5e681c30460f764b1ac35afc5163a1d | wc -l
```

If that says zero, try the other way `97f22113a5e681c30460f764b1ac35afc5163a1d..06c839536ba38c0cd78fb031af94cfa35e0fd0ba`

Comment: what is `wc -l` doing btw?

Comment: `wc` stands for word count. More details here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc or type `man wc` in your terminal

Comment: huh ok thanks, now I see it, why not "line count", I think we need line count, but I guess that is what the `-l` flag is for

Comment: thanks yeah it's weird that it doesn't trim whitespace, I had to do this `wc -l | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//'`

Answer (score 0):

@balki's answer is right:

```
git log --oneline 06c839536ba38c0cd78fb031af94cfa35e0fd0ba..97f22113a5e681c30460f764b1ac35afc5163a1d
```

As a real life example,
to see which git commits you have locally, which are not published to NPM, for example, use:

```
$ git log --oneline $(npm view . gitHead)..$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

and the output is the abbreviated hash, with the commit message/subject:

```
f4273e2 pdev:set
d61d726 pdev:set
10b85bc pdev:set
9eb2cbc pdev:set
```